# why wont my for loop execute when using strings

Tags: c++, string, loops

I am writing a program in C++ that formats phone numbers into international format. I used visual studios to compile my code and it indicates I do not have any errors, yet the for loop on line 21 keeps getting skipped and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string phonNumber; //to hold string
    string formattedNum = "+1-"; //to hold international format
    int count = 0; //to hold count index
    int i = 0; //to hold number index

    cout << "Please enter a phone number: "; //asks for phone number
    getline(cin, phonNumber); //use getline to get number and assign it to phonNumber

    int numOfDigits = phonNumber.length(); //gets length of phone number

    for (i = 0; i > numOfDigits || count > 10; i++) //runs a loop through the digits
    {
        if (phonNumber[i] <= '9' && phonNumber[i] >= '0') //reads only numbers
        {
            string formattedNum = formattedNum + phonNumber[i];
            if (count == 4) //4th digit is -
            {
                string formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";
            }
            if (count == 7) //7th digit is -
            {
                string formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";
            }
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        numOfDigits = count;
    }

    while (!(count > 10)) {
        formattedNum = formattedNum + "x";
        count++;
    }
    cout << "The properly formatted number is " << formattedNum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your condition is wrong, the loop stops when the condition is false (or rather as long as its true it keeps going). On first iteration i = 0 (so i> numDigits fails) and caount is also 0 so count > 10 also fails. which means you have false || false and the loop gets skipped.

Comment: `string formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";` -- You are redeclaring `formattedNum` again?  That is a different `formattedNum` than the one you declared earlier.  That `formattedNum` is a local variable within the loop.  You can see it's wrong by looking at what you did here: `numDigits = count;`.  You see that you didn't say `int numDigits = count;`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your condition seems wrong.
this condition:

```
for (i = 0; i > numOfDigits || count > 10; i++)
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < numOfDigits || count < 10; i++)
```

because the conditions inside the for loop should be the conditions for the loop to keep going, so with your condition above, the code block inside will never be reached

Comment: Thanks! the loop now initiates but has issues reading the string.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x76AC9AB2 in internationalPhoneFormat.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x010FF290.

Comment: @RemingtonValadez Look at this: `string formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";` -- do you see something wrong with that statement inside the loop?

Comment: `string formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";`

with these lines, your are declaring new string `formattedNum` so you can't get your purpose, just do the assignment, remove the leading `string`.

and with the for loop. remove the `i++` at the end, you already has it in the for loop, if you increase `i` each time in the loop, your result will go wrong

Comment: Thanks for the advice! it accepts the information and gives me the desired format. thanks to you both  @PaulMckenzie